# how to drag and drop actors on libgdx scene2d?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm developing a game using libGDX and I would like to know how I can drag and drop an Actor. I've made my stage and drawn the actor, but I don't know how to trigger that event.

Please try to help me using my own architecture.

```
public class MyGame implements ApplicationListener 
{
    Stage stage;
    Texture texture;
    Image actor;

    @Override
    public void create() 
    {       
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("actor.png"));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        stage = new Stage(512f,512f,true);

        actor = new Image(texture);
        stage.addActor(actor);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() 
    {       
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the Example in the libgdx examples. Here is the drag and drop test from the libgdx test classes: [DragAndDropTest](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/DragAndDropTest.java)

If you just want to drag/slide your Actor around you need to add a GestureListener to it and pass your Stage to the Inputprocessor like this:`Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);`.
Here is the [GestureDetectorTest](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/GestureDetectorTest.java) from libgdx.
For drag events its the Flinglistener.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to use `DragAndDrop` class, you can use this:

```
actor.addListener(new DragListener() {
    public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        actor.moveBy(x - actor.getWidth() / 2, y - actor.getHeight() / 2);
    }
});
```

Edit: method `drag` instead `touchDragged`

Answer (score 2):

In your main gamescreen class add a multiplexer so you can access events from different classes:

```
private InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(this);
```

After the gamescreen constructor add as an example:

```
inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(this);      
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(1, renderer3d.controller3d);  
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(2, renderer.controller2d);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(3, renderer3d.stage);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```

In your class that is using the actors use a DragListener as and example:

```
Actor.addListener((new DragListener() {
    public void touchDragged (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            // example code below for origin and position
            Actor.setOrigin(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
            Actor.setPosition(x, y);
            System.out.println("touchdragged" + x + ", " + y);

        }

    }));
```