# libGDX ingame store

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm working a on 2d endless sidescroller, using LibGDX. The game itself is already working, but now I want to add a kind of shop where the player can buy items like jetpacks, accessories etc for coins. What is the best way to store these items and how can I manage whether or not they're already bought?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a scene2d stage with actors for that. And you can implement it by dragging some items from one side of the screen and dropping them in another. For example, you may have a table which contains your items and the player can drag and drop some of these items in another part of the screen and this is the way they will buy things. In order to drag items you can implement a method like:

```
 actor.addListener(new DragListener() {
   public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {

    }
  });
```

or simply use a normal stage input listener like:

```
public void touchDragged (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {

}
```

Have a look at the libgdx dragAndDrop test [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/DragAndDropTest.java) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287759/how-to-drag-and-drop-actors-on-libgdx-scene2d) .

If you don't like the drag and drop idea you can simply create a table containing various items (again using scene 2d) and on a click on an item simply add/increment the item to the player's inventory. This is quite straightforward.

As regards to whether the player has already bought some items you can create an array with actors/items for the player and when the player drags some items to the other part of the screen to buy stuff simply add the items to the array. In this way you will keep track of the items bought..